# How to clearly but politely explain to commenters/answerers that they aren't answering the question?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985618/maximum-number-of-degree-of-freedom-for-lm-feasible-algorithm-in-octave?noredirect=1#comment100618276_56985618) about the limitations of an Octave algorithm I point out during my work, but I can't find this limitation clearly written anywhere. I thought that the limitations I go through are due to a part of the context I didn't understand. I wrote the question in bold to highlight that, even with context, I want this particular point to be addressed. However, in the comments and only answer, people only addressed the finite element analysis part (which is just context) and never the optimization part (core of the question).

**How may I edit to lead people to actually answer the question?** They seem to know what they are talking about, but they are still discussing context and not the question.

Comment: Keep doing what you're doing - engage with the people who are at least trying to answer. What you ask about is not exactly common knowledge, so be glad you are at least getting some activity on it.

Comment: I’d reply to the answer directly explaining the problem. As for the question, I’ve seen a few people put their question first and then put the context below it. Maybe that would help here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's a sure sign that people really appreciate the opportunity to work on it, which means you've contributed a really good question.

Folks (and by folks, I also mean me) sometimes have a tendency to start writing the second we *think* we understand the problem without fully realizing that we've only actually *read* 1/3 of the question, even if we did actually make it to the end. Part of that is just the rush you get seeing an opportunity to engage with a really interesting problem and, to some extent, the desire to be the first one to get a good answer written.

It's best to just embrace the enthusiasm in this case and (as patiently as possible) let folks know they missed something, while making strategic use of bold and italics to help steer their attention where it needs to be.

It's a great problem to have when you've asked something that requires rather specialized knowledge and very quickly see people that probably know how to help you engaging, but herding that enthusiasm can be a bit tricky sometimes.